# Formatting Slack notification from Travis

Tags: travis-ci, slack, slack-api

Is it possible to format a Slack notification template in Travis, in order to use **bold**, *italic* and [links](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#Configuring-slack-notifications)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using slack emphasis (basically it is like markdown) text? 
Try surrounding words in ** like ***so*** for bold.

```
*bold* will show as bold
_itaic_ will show as italic
~strikethrough~ will show as strikethrough
>will indent a line
>>> will indent multiple paragraphs
```

Source:
https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages

As for links refer to: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't work.
After a bit of research, I've found out that the notifications are not sending required field that will enable markdown, although default messages do.

Comment: Can you please share the info about that markdown field?

Comment: mrkdwn, mrkdwn_in.